# File Search c++

Tags: c++

what is the best way of searching files on windows in c++. Should I use boost or there is a better way . I'm encountering some problems with building  filesystem library. I found this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <dir.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define ALL_ATTS (FA_DIREC | FA_ARCH) 

void walker(const char *, const char *);

void walker(const char *path, const char *findme)
{
 struct ffblk  finder;
 unsigned int  res;

 chdir(path);

 for (res = findfirst("*.*", &finder, ALL_ATTS); res == 0; res = findnext(&finder))
 {
 if (strcmp(finder.ff_name, ".") == 0) continue;   /* current dir */
 if (strcmp(finder.ff_name, "..") == 0) continue;  /* parent dir  */

 /* 
 * If its a directory, examine it
 * else compare the filename with the one we're looking for
 */
 if (finder.ff_attrib & FA_DIREC)
 {
  char newpath[MAXPATH];
  strcpy(newpath, path);
  strcat(newpath, "\\");
  strcat(newpath, finder.ff_name);
  chdir(finder.ff_name);
  walker(newpath, findme);
  chdir("..");
  }
  else
  {
  if (strcmp(finder.ff_name, findme) == 0)
  {
    printf("Found in: %s\n", path);
   }
   }
  }
  }

   int main(void)
  {
  const char *root = "\\";
  char buf[BUFSIZ];

   printf ("This program will find a file on the current drive.\n"
      "Enter the name of the file to look for: ");

   fflush(stdout);  

   if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin))
   {
   strtok(buf, "\n");  /* Remove the newline character */
   walker(root, buf);
   }

    return(0);
   }
```

But none of the versions of dir headers works ...

Comment: There are only one way to work, but so many way for not working...

Comment: @rodrigo, don't get your comment (or it's relevance).. :(

Comment: I would not use boost unless you are already using it in your project, however the boost filesystem library is quite neat.

Comment: @Nim What I mean is that if you say "this works" all is clear, but if you say (as the OP says) "this does not work" you know nothing about what happens, you need to know "how is not working": not compiling, not linking, not doing what you expect, what errors happen, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found boost::filesystem to work quite well, as long as you know what you are doing.  The following works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const std::string start = "C:\\";
    const std::string findme = "winsock.dll";

    fs::recursive_directory_iterator end;
    fs::recursive_directory_iterator rdi(start);

    while(rdi != end)
    {
        const std::string path = rdi->path().string();
        if(path.find(findme) != std::string::npos)
        {
            std::cout << path << std::endl;
        }

        try
        {
            ++rdi;  // various system directories can bork this
        }
        catch(fs::filesystem_error e)
        {
            rdi.no_push();    // don't try to recurse into it
            ++rdi;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider Win32 APIs like `FindFirstFile`,`FindNextFile`, etc.

There are some sample codes on MSDN, like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the [recls](http://synesis.com.au/software/recls/) library made by Matthew Wilson.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've found looks like it uses functions specific to some particular "standard" library (and may even have been written for MS-DOS). Secondarily, it uses a depth-first search; for directory searching, I usually prefer a breadth-first search.

I'd try to use Windows desktop search and/or Windows Search as the first choices. These will use pre-built indexes for really fast results if the user has that enabled.

If that's not available, I'd use code for a breadth-first search, which looks roughly like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <queue>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

// I think MS's names for some things are obnoxious.
const HANDLE HNULL = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
const int A_DIR = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY;

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, FILETIME const &ft) {
    SYSTEMTIME utc, lt;
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &utc);
    SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(NULL, &utc, &lt);

    return os << lt.wHour << ":" << lt.wMinute << ":" << lt.wSecond << "." << lt.wMilliseconds;
}

void process(std::string const &path, WIN32_FIND_DATA const &file) { 
    std::cout << file.ftCreationTime << "\t" << path << file.cFileName << "\n";
}

void find_file(std::string const &folder_name, std::string const &fmask) {
    HANDLE finder;          // for FindFirstFile
    WIN32_FIND_DATA file;   // data about current file.
    std::priority_queue<std::string, std::vector<std::string>, std::greater<std::string> > dirs;
    dirs.push(folder_name); // start with passed directory 

    do {
        std::string path = dirs.top();// retrieve directory to search
        dirs.pop();

        if (path[path.size()-1] != '\\')  // normalize the name.
            path += "\\";

        std::string mask = path + fmask;    // create mask for searching

        // traverse a directory.
        if (HNULL==(finder=FindFirstFile(mask.c_str(), &file))) {
            continue;
        }
        do { 
            if (!(file.dwFileAttributes & A_DIR)) // print file names
                process(path, file);
        } while (FindNextFile(finder, &file));
        FindClose(finder);
        if (HNULL==(finder=FindFirstFile((path + "*").c_str(), &file)))
            continue;
        do { 
            if ((file.dwFileAttributes & A_DIR) && (file.cFileName[0] != '.'))
                dirs.push(path + file.cFileName);
        } while (FindNextFile(finder, &file));
        FindClose(finder);
    } while (!dirs.empty());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    if (argc > 2)
        find_file(argv[1], argv[2]);
    else
        find_file("C:\\", "*");
    return 0;
}
```